# How to show non-persistent fields for an in-memory object in Apache ISIS?

Tags: isis

I have an Apache ISIS @Action that creates and returns a list of in-memory objects. When those objects are displayed by Apache ISIS as a collection in the browser - the JodaTime `DateTime` and `String` fields become all null.

There is also another field on the object, which is a persistent entity - it does not get reset to null and is displayed on the object.

Is it possible to display values of non-persistent fields of an object?

EDIT: Apparently the `String` field is displayed. The `DateTime` are not though. Can this be an issue with `DateTime` specifically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here is to use JAXB view models, as per [concepts](http://isis.apache.org/guides/ugfun/ugfun.html#_ugfun_building-blocks_types-of-domain-objects_view-models) and the [programming model](http://isis.apache.org/guides/ugfun/ugfun.html#_ugfun_programming-model_view-models_jaxb).

One thing that isn't documented yet is that, for Joda date/time fields, you'll need to annotated the fields (or properties) with a JAXB XmlAdapter; see [this blog post](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-joda-time-dates-and-times.html) for guidance.

HTH, Dan